# Getting instance of Assembly is it possible in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Here is my problem

Like window :

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyPath);
```

I want to achieve same for Mac where AssemblyPath is path of static library (libTEST.a) and i want to create instance of this library. Is it possible in Mac?

Comment: I don't know a way to load a static lib. you could load a NSBundle at runtime or a dylib but I don't know how to load a .a -- so I guess: no

Comment: What programming language is that? C#? It might make more sense to tag this question Mono or C# instead of Objective-C, as you're not looking for an Objective-C answer.

Comment: he is. he wants to load a static lib the way he loads assemblies in objC. I think it is bundles or dylibs

Comment: I want to load library in Objective-C(Mac) not for c#..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-c:
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:AssemblyPath];
[b load];

where AssemblyPath : framework path.

Answer (score 0):

No. Static libraries must be compiled into your project. Drag the library into the link targets field in Xcode or just `-l<library name>` if building from the command line to link the static library into your code. Don't forget the header (.h) files as well.

I should note that it isn't just OS X or Objective-C that mandates this. This is how C-based linking works.

Answer (score -1):

We cant create instance of a library on Mac but even we can use the methods in it by importing it to the project

Comment: why the down votes. can you really dynamically load a static lib? .. I know about dylibs and I know you could make it all an NSBundle but LML is right AFAIK

Comment: Yes I am also get confused with this downvote.Can u please tell me how wrong I said here.If I am wrong comment with correct answer